# Error adding library in Android studio: Gradle project syns failed: > Failed to apply plugin 'com.frogermcs.androiddevmetrics'

Tags: android

I imported the [xabber-android](https://github.com/redsolution/xabber-android) project into Android Studio. There were many different errors during build. I fixed everything, except one:

```
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.frogermcs.androiddevmetrics']
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.frogermcs.androiddevmetrics'.
   > Configuration with name 'releaseCompile' not found.
```

I tried different ways to fix this, but nothing worked. Practically, there aren't any solutions on the Internet to problems related specifically to the releaseCompile() configuration. The error is probably related to something else, but due to my inexperience I cannot solve this problem. How can I fix it?

#### File *xabber\build.gradle*

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "realm-android"
    id "com.frogermcs.androiddevmetrics"
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    buildToolsVersion '33.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 29
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 644
        versionName '2.6.6.644'
        manifestPlaceholders = [crashlytics:getLocalProperty("crashlytics.key")]
    }

    lintOptions {
        // Problems with generated "applicationId" string resource
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
        disable 'InvalidPackage'

        abortOnError false
    }

    subprojects {
        afterEvaluate {
            if (getPlugins().hasPlugin('android') ||
                    getPlugins().hasPlugin('android-library')) {

                configure(android.lintOptions) {
                    abortOnError false

                }
            }
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "destribution", "build"
    productFlavors {

        open {
            dimension "destribution"
            versionNameSuffix "-open"
        }

        store {
            dimension "destribution"
        }

        dev {
            dimension "build"
            applicationId "com.xabber.androiddev"
            resValue 'string', 'application_package', applicationId
            multiDexEnabled true
        }

        beta {
            dimension "build"
            applicationId "com.xabber.android.beta"
            resValue 'string', 'application_package', applicationId
            multiDexEnabled true
        }

        prod {
            dimension "build"
            applicationId "com.xabber.android"
            resValue 'string', 'application_package', applicationId
            multiDexEnabled true
        }

        vip {
            dimension "build"
            applicationId "com.xabber.androidvip"
            resValue 'string', 'application_package', applicationId
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'mips', 'x86', 'x86_64'
            universalApk true
        }
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            includeAndroidResources = true
        }
    }
}

def getLocalProperty(String propertyName) {
    def propsFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
    if (propsFile.exists()) {
        def props = new Properties()
        props.load(new FileInputStream(propsFile))
        if (props[propertyName] != null) return props[propertyName]
        else return ""
    } else {
        return ""
    }
}

if (getGradle().getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString().contains("Store")) {
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
}

ext {
    smackVerstion = 'ffb99cc'
}

dependencies {

    implementation project(path: 'MemorizingTrustManager', configuration: 'default')
    implementation project(path: 'emojicon', configuration: 'default')

    // Smack
    implementation "com.github.str4tocaster.smack:smack-android-extensions:$smackVerstion"
    implementation "com.github.str4tocaster.smack:smack-experimental:$smackVerstion"
    implementation "com.github.str4tocaster.smack:smack-tcp:$smackVerstion"
    implementation "com.github.str4tocaster.smack:smack-resolver-dnsjava:$smackVerstion"

    // Android support
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

    // Firebase
    storeImplementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.2.1'

    // otr
    implementation 'com.github.redsolution:otr4j:custom-SNAPSHOT'

    // Barcode scanner
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:android-integration:3.3.0'

    // Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.5.0'

    // RxJava
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.3.8'

    // Social media
    storeImplementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:16.2.0'
    storeImplementation "com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.0.0"

    // gms
    storeImplementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:18.0.1'
    storeImplementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.7.0'
    storeImplementation ('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:2.2.0') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }

    // okhttp
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.5.0'

    // Event bus
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.3.1'

    // Commons IO
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:20030203.000550'

    // Bouncy Castle
    implementation group: 'org.bouncycastle', name: 'bcpkix-jdk15on', version: '1.70'

    // UI
    implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:2.1.6@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    implementation 'ru.egslava:MaskedEditText:1.0.5'
    implementation 'eu.davidea:flexible-adapter:5.0.0-rc4'
    implementation 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.1@aar'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'

    // Crashlytics
    storeImplementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    // Leak Canary
    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.12'
    releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.6.3'

    // Block Canary
    debugImplementation 'com.github.markzhai:blockcanary-android:1.5.0'
    releaseImplementation 'com.github.markzhai:blockcanary-no-op:1.5.0'

    // Test
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.10.3'
    releaseImplementation 'org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:4.10.3'
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module:'guava-jdk5'
}
```

#### File *build.gradle*

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        agp_version2 = '8.0.1'
        agp_version = agp_version2
        agp_version1 = '8.1.2'
    }
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$agp_version1"
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'com.frogermcs.androiddevmetrics:androiddevmetrics-plugin:0.7'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:10.15.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
        maven { url 'http://igniterealtime.org/repo' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
}
```